# Convert a integer to a String in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I want to convert a single integer to string in Pandas not a whole column or row. However, Pandas won't allow me to use str(i) which i is an integer and have the error module object is not callable.
How should I fix this?

So I have an index i = 5
I want to append this to a string `str = '[' +str(i)+']'`
My expectation would be str = [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVVPh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVVPh.png)

Comment: You've likely shadowed the built-in function `str` with some variable `str = 'some string'` Now `str(i)` won't work.

Comment: Provide a quick example with mock data and show what you are expecting.

Comment: Hi, I add the expecting result

Answer (score 1):

you can you [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), for example, I create a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["A","B","C"],
                   "col2":[1,2,3]})
df.head()
```

output:

```
   col1 col2
0   A   1
1   B   2
2   C   3
```

and turn the value 3 in col2 to str:

```
temp = df.col2[2].astype(str)
temp, type(temp)
```

output:

```
('3', numpy.str_)
```

OR, The f-string can be you in your case:

```
str = f"something here {df.index[i]} something here"
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am working on column index. For example, I want to write specific sell value in certain format: [1,2]: 12.4. So I want the data "[1,2]: 12.4" as a string into another cell. Counting index can be done through a loop but I can't convert the index to string

Comment: you can use this `str(df.index[i])`, or you can use the f-string to write a string with value `str = f"some thing here {df.index[i]} some thing here"`

Comment: The f-string solve my problem!!!! Thank you so much Truong!!! I really appreciate that!!!!

Comment: Good to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

The whole column will turn into `'object'`(which means 'string' data in this case) when you change any single one element of the numerical column into `'string'`.

You can try with:

```
df.colA[0] = str(df.colA[0])
# Then check the column 'colA' if its dtype is 'object'
df.colA
```